# Problem getting just created Groups programmatically

Tags: permissions, groups, roles

I'm encountering some problems getting "newly created" groups..

This is the code I'm using:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteCollectionDestinazione))
            {
                using (SPWeb web2 = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web2.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    try
                    {
                        web2.SiteGroups.Add(name, ownername, owner, description);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Already in use");
                    }

                    ritorno = web2.SiteGroups[name];

                    web2.AssociatedGroups.Add(ritorno);
                    web2.Update();

                    foreach (SPUser user in gruppoDaCopiare.Users)
                    {
                        ritorno.AddUser(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The things that makes me crazy is that another function very similar works:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteCollection))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    try
                    {
                        web.SiteGroups.Add(name, ownername, owner, description);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Already in use");
                    }

                    ritorno = web.SiteGroups[name];

                    web.AssociatedGroups.Add(ritorno);
                    web.Update();

                    foreach (SPUser userin gruppoDaCopiare.Users)
                    {
                        ritorno.AddUser(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

How could it be possible? What's wrong with this code? I also tried to Update the SPWeb after the "new user" created, but it doesn't work...

Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

EDIT:
If I try to Add newly that group it tolds me that the name is already used but I cannot access it by SiteGroups["Name"]

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you getting an error?

Comment: An exception on ritorno = web2.SiteGroups[name] that tolds me the group named "name" doesn't exist..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found out now what's the problem: I'm passing an SPMember instead of an SPUser as Owner, so it compiles, seems to work, but fails without raise any exception!

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteCollectionDestinazione))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    try
                    {
                    SPUser owner = web.EnsureUser(groupToCopy.Users.GetByID(groupToCopy.Owner.ID).LoginName);
                    web.SiteGroups.Add(groupToCopy.Name, owner, owner, groupToCopy.Description);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Group  " + groupToCopy.Name + " already exists");
                    }

                    web.AssociatedGroups.Add(web.SiteGroups[groupToCopy.Name]);
                    web.Update();

                    ritorno = web.SiteGroups[groupToCopy.Name];

                    foreach (SPUser utente in groupToCopy.Users)
                    {
                        SPUser utenteSito = web.EnsureUser(utente.LoginName);
                        ritorno.AddUser(utenteSito);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return ritorno;
```

Comment: Can you add the working sample code?

Comment: AllowUnsafe is a terrible idea in this scenario. See my answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27990/allowunsafeupdates-vs-spsecurity-runwithelevatedprivileges

Also, RWEP is not necessary. That same answer presents a better alternative.

If the current user cannot maintain groups, then why force it? You don't describe your scenario, so it is hard to give pertainant advice.