# Difference between AllowUnsafeUpdates and RunwithElevatedprevilizes in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AllowUnsafeUpdates vs SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27990/allowunsafeupdates-vs-spsecurity-runwithelevatedprivileges)

Can Any one explain the basic difference between allow unsafe updates and runwithelevatedprevilizes in sharepoint 2010. Can any one please explain form low level and when to use it?

Regards,
Suresh Pydi